# Do we need commas after "she/he said" in a dialogue?

Tags: commas

If a person is saying "And then, she/he said '________'", do we need commas after "said"? It's written in a dialogue, not a narrative. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related questions, [He said “she is pretty”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101943/he-said-she-is-pretty) and [Does a comma have to be used before a quotation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/does-a-comma-have-to-be-used-before-a-quotation),

Comment: @SilverSolver- StoneyB's answer below is correct in my experience, but I would also prefer to remove the comma after "then" in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Separating the matrix verb from its spoken object with a comma is a very widely observed ***convention***, and your teacher/publisher will almost certainly insist on it, even though it is entirely superfluous if you are using quotation marks.